# VSTS Azure PowerShell Task SQL Firewall rules

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-devops

I try to update my database on SQL Azure from VSTS.

I need to apply a firewall rules during the migration and remove it after.

I'm using a VSTS Azure PowerShell Task, I've configured it and I try this command to add a rule:

```
New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule -ServerName $serverName -RuleName $firewallRule -StartIpAddress $currentPublicIp -EndIpAddress $currentPublicIp
```

The task fails with this error message:

```
##[error]No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default <subscriptionName> to set the default subscription.
```

The task is starting with this in logs:

```
##[command]Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant ******** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud
##[command]Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -TenantId ********
```

Comment: In VSTS, you selected a ARM subscription, but `New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule ` is a classic cmdlet. You should use `New-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName "" -ServerName "" -FirewallRuleName "Rule01" -StartIpAddress "192.168.0.198" -EndIpAddress "192.168.0.199"`

Comment: Thanks Walter, just to know classic cmdlet are supposed to be deprecated in favor of ARM or both have their advantages?

Comment: Maybe you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ARM cmdlet for the SQL DB, not ASM one. Notice the `RM` in cmdlets.

```
New-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule
Set-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule
```